# Changing Input opacity on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

For some reason the :Active tag doesn't make the button disappear or turn to opacity 0.0 any ideas?

```css
#button1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  top: 500px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
#button1:hover {
  width: 270px;
  height: 60px;
}
#button1:visited {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
```

```html
<a href="test" target="_blank">
  <input type="image" id="button1" src="button.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: `#button1:visited { display: none }` ?

Comment: @PauliusK. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=qDtwSPN74V Doesn't work

Comment: You can use `#button1:active { display: none }` that's all. Forgot that :visited is only for links, mb.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this without JavaScript is to use CSS target. First, give you provide an `id` attribute for your link:

```
<a id="test" href="#test">
  <input type="image" id="button1" src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/138.jpg" />
</a>
```

Next, you target that id in your CSS:

```
#test:target {
  display: none;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the visited selector on anything but a link. Even though you've wrapped your input in an anchor tag, it won't work to try and select it with the visited selector.

You can use #Button1:active instead or give the anchor element an id and use that #anchorTagID:visited

Comment: Is there any what I can just have them when they click on the input it disappears?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2NMZ/180/#&togetherjs=wwKcmVHQRN I tried this but to no avail... :(